# How to use a condition with "COUNT" in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, count

I am getting error in this query,

```
SELECT count(if(state=0)) FROM `nagios`.`nagios_hostchecks`
where `nagios_hostchecks`.`start_time` like '%2012-01-02%'
and `nagios_hostchecks`.`host_object_id`=60;
```

Comment: Mind posting the error you received?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM `nagios`.`nagios_hostchecks` 
WHERE `nagios_hostchecks`.`start_time` like '%2012-01-02%' 
    AND 
`nagios_hostchecks`.`host_object_id`=60
    AND
`state` = 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

Just a quick guess without checking nagios schema

```
SELECT count(*) FROM nagios.nagios_hostchecks
WHERE state=0 AND nagios_hostchecks.start_time like '%2012-01-02%' 
AND nagios_hostchecks.host_object_id=60;
```